# How to remove android activity label (activity title) and label bar?

Tags: android, android-styles

I added `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` to the manifest file but the app doesn't open. I want to remove the `Activity` label in which the name of the `Activity` is written.

> Here is part of manifest file:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change extends in your MainActivity.

Change this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
}
```

For this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Set

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: label still remaining and app isnt opening

Comment: I dont know how to post image

Comment: Holo theme was deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 
        `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` Just insert in it immediately after your `onCreate` function

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}
```

You may have to change your `extends AppCompatActivity` to `extends Activity` sometimes to work without error